# why I am not receiving any mail from sendgrid?

Tags: node.js, twilio, sendgrid, mern

what is wrong with my code? I have also made a single sender verification with the mentioned email in the code on sendgrid and am getting this notification "Your account is temporarily under review".Why is it happening ?

```
router.post('/delete-account',(req,res)=>{
  User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).then(user=>{
    if(!user){
      return res.status(422).json({error:"Invalid credentials"})
  }
    user.save().then((user)=>{
        const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
        sgMail.setApiKey("**************************************************")
        const msg = {
          to: user.email, // Change to your recipient
          from: 'money148001@gmail.com', // Change to your verified sender
          subject: 'Delete Account Request',
          text: 'Explore and enjoy beautiful posts and videos by making a lot of friends online',
          html: `Hii <strong>${user.username}</strong> we have seen your request for deleting the account. You are just one step away now. Kindly email us the reason behind deleting it and get it deleted permanently.<br>
                 <h2>Have a good day..!!!</h2>`
        }
        sgMail
          .send(msg)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Email sent')
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
          })
           res.json({message:"Check your email messages for further information"})
       })
  })
})
```

This following is my client side program where I will be calling the above mentioned program

```
import React,{useState,useContext,} from 'react'
import {Link,useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import M from 'materialize-css'
import {UserContext} from '../../App'
const DeleteAccount  = ()=>{
    const history = useHistory()
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("")
    const[passward,setPasword] = useState("")
    const {state,dispatch} = useContext(UserContext)
    const [isPasswordShown,setIsPasswordShown] = useState(false);
    const togglePassword = () =>{
        setIsPasswordShown(!isPasswordShown);
   }
    const PostData = ()=>{
        if(!/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email)){
            M.toast({html: "Invalid email",classes:"#c62828 red darken-3"})
            return
        }
        fetch('/delete-account',{
            method:"post",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                email,
                passward
            })
        }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{
           if(data.error){
              M.toast({html: data.error,classes:"#c62828 red darken-3"})
           }
           else{
               M.toast({html:data.message,classes:"#43a047 green darken-1"})
               localStorage.clear()
               dispatch({type:"CLEAR"})
               history.push('/signin')
           }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
   return (
      <div className="mycard">
          <div className="card auth-card input-field">
            <h2>Instagram</h2>
            <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter your email id"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
            type={isPasswordShown ? "text":"password"}
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            value={passward}
            onChange={(e)=>setPasword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button style={{fontSize:"15px"}} className="btn #64b5f6 blue darken-1" onClick={togglePassword}>
            {isPasswordShown===true?<p style={{fontSize: "15px",marginTop:"0px"}}>Hide Password</p>:<p style={{fontSize: "15px",marginTop:"0px"}}>Show Password</p>} <i style={{fontSize:"15px"}} className="far fa-eye"></i>
          </button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
            <button className="btn #c62828 red darken-3"
            onClick={()=>PostData()}
            >
               Delete My Account
            </button>
            
    
        </div>
      </div>
   )
}


export default DeleteAccount
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you believe you're not receiving e-mail sent via SendGrid, if not due to the fact that your SendGrid account is under review? It's not clear why you believe it's an issue with your code, and not with the fact that you've seemingly been blocked from using the service.

Comment: but why do you think am blocked ? I don't know what 's the problem with the sendgrid ,I even tried by my friend's mail id ,but still it is showing the same error

Comment: I'm not sure how I or anyone here who's not a SendGrid employee could possibly know the answer to that. This is a question for SendGrid's support team, not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

If you are getting the notification that "Your account is temporarily under review" then your account is currently part of the review process. You can read about what the [SendGrid account review process looks like here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/account-under-review).

You should have been sent an email from SendGrid to your account's email address to let you know which stage of review you are under; warned, suspended, deactivated and banned.

That email will likely ask you for more details about your account usage and you should respond to the email with as much detail as possible. Giving the account team as much information as you can will help them to reactivate your account quicker.

If you cannot find this email from the SendGrid team, I recommend you [contact SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us).

I hope you get unblocked swiftly.

Comment: not sure their support is much use if you have to log in to get it...